# creating a play / pause toggle switch

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, smf, mmppf

I am using silverlight 4 with smf and I want to create a play , pause toggle button. So if the media is playing and if the button is clicked it will pause the video. But if the media is paused, it will restart playing video. 
How can I do that

```
 private void btnPlay_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {



        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about silverlight, but you could use a boolean.

```
private void btnPlay_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     if(isPlaying)
     {
         music.pause();
         isPlaying = FALSE;
         return;
     }

     music.play();
     isPlaying = TRUE;
     return;
}
```